# Старорусский язык

Tags: старославянский

В фантастике попадание героя в прошлое - довольно частый сюжет. И всегда в такой ситуации герой прекрасно общается с соотечественниками, жившими 300, а то и 500 лет назад, без каких-либо языковых барьеров. А если предположить, что наш современник, не лингвист, действительно попадет, скажем, во времена Петра I, а то и Ивана Грозного, сможет ли он понимать речь людей того времени (не говорить, а хотя бы просто понимать)? И будут ли они, в свою очередь, понимать его хотя бы частично (без учета современных слов, вроде "самолета" или "телевизора")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот отрывок из письма А.Курбского царю Иоанну:

"Коего зла и гонения от тебе не претерпех! И коих бед и напастей на мя не подвигл еси! И коих лъжей и измен на мя не възвел еси! А вся приключившася ми ся от тобе различныя беды по ряду, за множество их, не могу изрещи, понеже горестью еще душа моя объята бысть. Но вкупе вся реку конешне: всего лишен бых и от земли божия тобою туне отогнан бых. И воздал еси мне злая воз благая и за возлюбление мое — непримирительную ненависть. И кровь моя, яко вода, пролитая за тя, вопиет на тя к богу моему. Бог — сердцам зритель — во уме моем прилежно смышлях и совесть мою свидетеля поставлях, и исках, и зрех, мысленно обращался, и не вем себе, и не наидох в чем пред тобою согрешивша."

Разве непонятно? Да это еще письменная речь,насыщенная старославянизмами, характерная для образованных  людей. В быту в ХVI веке русские люди говорили не так уж отлично от нас с вами.

Comment: У вас не запись XVI века, а "суржик". Текст без адаптации читать немного сложнее, выбрал кусок где поменьше церковной лексики

>Како же сего не моглъ еси разсудити, яко подобаетъ властелемъ не звѣрски яритися, ниже безсловесно смирятися? Якоже рече апостолъ: «Овехъ убо милуйте разсуждающе, овехъ же страхомъ спасайте, от огня восхищающе».Видиши ли, яко апостолъ страхомъ повелѣваетъ спасати? Тако же и во благочестивыхъ царѣхъ и временехъ много обрящеши злѣйшее мучение.

Читать естественно можно, как и украинский. А вот фонетичекие различия гораздо серьёзней, на адаптацию потребоволась бы время.

Comment: Но, думаю, что через месяц где-то уже понимали бы легко, а вот говорить научились бы намного позже.  
А вообще сразу вспомнился режиссер Якин: "Языками не владею, ваше благородие")))))))))

Comment: Украинский совершенно идентичен русскому в смысле синтаксиса, но лексически и идиоматически творцами мовы отдален от русского совершенно сознательно.Терминологичекий пример: Вот какую эволюцию уже в ХХ веке совершили "местоимение" («містоімення" - "містойменник" - "заіменник – "займенник"), "имя числительное" («ім`я числове" - "ймення чисельне" – "чисельник" – "числівник"), "запятая" («запята" – "запинка" – "кома"), "двоеточие" («двоеточка" – "двокрапка"), "сказуемое" («сказуєме" - "сказуюче" - "присудок") и другие термины.

Comment: Мужской род стал "мужським", затем "мужеським" и, наконец, "чоловічим". Соответственно "женский", последовательно превратился "женський", "жінський", "жіночий" и т.д. Остановиться уже не могли и только спорили, какое название лучше обеспечивает независимость украинского языка от русского: "іменник" или "предметник", "прикметник" или "призначник", "присудок" или "присудень", "лапки"(кавычки) или "цятки" и т.п. -- Постепенно сами украинизаторы стали задаваться вопросом: "Куда ведёт нас это буйное, но беспорядочное и ненаучное языковое творчество?

Comment: Зато как занимательно читать берестяные грамоты!Грамота № 109 (ок. 1100 г.)[15] о покупке краденой рабыни дружинником. Живая русская речь 900 лет тому назад (расставлены современные знаки препинания). Грамота написана по одноеровой системе: ъ выступает как на месте этимологического ъ (читается как сверхкраткое [о]: кънягыни), так и на месте этимологического ь (читается как сверхкраткое [е]: Плъскове, чъто вместо Пльсковѣ, чьто).

Comment: Вместо ятя везде пишется е:
Грамота ꙍтъ Жизномира къ Микоулє. Коупилъ єси [ты купил; «еси» — связка] робоу [рабыню] Плъсковє [в Пскове], а нынє мѧ въ томъ ѧла [за это схватила] кънѧгыни. А нынє сѧ дроужина по мѧ пороучила [поручилась]. А нынє ка посъли къ томоу моужєви [человеку] грамотоу, єли [если] оу нєго роба. А сє ти хочоу конє коупивъ, и кнѧжъ моужъ всадивъ, та на съводы [очные ставки]. А ты атчє [если] єси нє възалъ коунъ [денег] тєхъ, а нє ємли [бери] ничъто жє оу.

Answer (score 4):

То
 насколько вы будете понимать эту речь, можете судить по тому насколько 
вы понимаете речь белорусскую и украинскую. Эти языки разошлись с 
русским примерно в это время. Т.е., если нет психологического барьера, в
 основном все понятно, но тормозишь из-за мысленного перевода.

Если говорить про собственный опыт, то когда в юности отдыхал в Крыму (еще 
украинском), медленную украинскую речь начал нормально воспринимать 
где-то на третий день. Будь в этом необходиимость, думаю научился бы на 
нем выражать свои мысли в течении одного-двух месяцев.

Кстати, если говорить о книгах, разница языка современного и XVII в. 
обыграна в романе Б. Акунина "Детская книга".

Comment: Интересно, а где в Крыму можно было наткнуться на украинскую речь? Разве что в Украинском театре, и то, если повезет, так как две трети репертуара было на русском языке.Билеты туда распространяли бесплатно(на украинскую классику) в школах и ПТУ.А добровольцев идти на украинские спектакли практически не было. Подписка на главную газету Крыма "Крымская правда" в советские времена была около 300 000 на русском языке и около 200 экземпляров на украинском. Крымчане знакомились с укр.мовою при помощи Киевского ТВ да иногда по вывескам типа ""Їдальня" либо "М'ясо" - кого-то обязывали соответствовать

Comment: @Варяг-91, по большому счёту только украинское ТВ и редкие украинизмы в речи местных, однако для меня это было сильно в новинку и потому интересно. На 3-й день смотреть украинские каналы я уже мог.

Comment: Вообще-то, я живу в Крыму, так что, можно сказать, информация из первых рук. Так вот, по-украински тут не говорит практически никто (за редким исключением). Да, телевидение и радио было на украинском - но и только. Теперь же, когда мы Россия, этого нет. В театра тоже не помню, чтобы шли пьесы на украинском. В Украинском театре в основном выступают с гастролями разными певцы, а сам он, скорее, театр оперетты.  
Но вообще, я понимаю оба языка одинаково хорошо.

Answer (score 3):

Дело в том, что пока ещё, т.е. на уровне ныне живущего поколения, это возможно, но наши внуки, или лет через 15, когда СМИ и реклама окончательно превратят русский язык в американский суржик и он будет относиться не к славянской языковой семье, а к германской, то тогда старорусский язык будет совершенно непонятен и, по сути, будет иностранным языком. Хотя для меня уже нынешняя гламурная феня является иностранной мовой.

Comment: Это уж точно...